# Question about differentiation and directional derivatives.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Given $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $Df(x_0)=0$, then all directional derivatives at $x_0$ equal $0$. Is this true?

Comment: What does $D$ do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative along direction $h$ is obtained by evaluating the operator $Df(x_0)$ at $h$. If the operator is zero, then the directional derivative is zero in any direction.

In the special case $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, the operator $Df(x_0)$ is represented by the gradient $\nabla f(x_0) : =\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_0) \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_0)\end{bmatrix}$, and the directional derivative along direction $h \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is $(\nabla f(x_0))^\top h$. If the gradient is zero, then the directional derivatives are zero.

Comment: Okay, that is kind of the idea I was thinking.  Thanks.